# How to add text from textarea to a div

Tags: html, textarea

I have tried get the text of textarea(multiple lines) and set the text to a div.
But the div only have one line for the text from textarea

This is my code:

```
//html structure
<div>

    <textarea id="cmt_content" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
    <br> <input id="addAccordion" type="button" value="ADD COMMENT" />
</div>
<div id="rs">
</div>

//script
$('#addAccordion').click(function(){
    var content = document.createElement("div");
    content.appendChild(document.createTextNode($("#cmt_content").val()));
    $('#rs').append(content);
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to convert the newlines into proper HTML `<br>` tags.

```
var html = $("#cmt_content").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
```

Then simply set that as the innerHTML of the div you created:

```
content.innerHTML = html;
```

Or you could combine it into one line:

```
content.innerHTML = $("#cmt_content").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
```

See live example: http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/RhHaS/

Final code:

```
$('#addAccordion').click(function(){
    var content = document.createElement("div");
    content.innerHTML = $("#cmt_content").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
    $('#rs').append(content);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following scenario you're describing works, I guess you're just having problems with new lines

Is this better?

```
$('#addAccordion').click(function(){
    var content = $("<div>");
    content.append($("#cmt_content").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br />'));
    $('#rs').append(content);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZahVy/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addAccordion').click(function () {
            var value = $("#cmt_content").val().replace(/\n/g, '</br>')
            $('#rs').append('<div>' + value+'</div>' );
        });
    });
```